# logistic groth model and USA population

Tags: numerical-methods, mathematical-modeling

logistic growth mode 
$$P(t)=\frac{P_l}{1-ce^{-k*t}} $$

$P_l$,$c,k$ are constants
P(t) population at time t
$P_L$ is the carrying capacity

find constants with $P(0)=76.212$,$P(30)=122.775$,$P(60)=179.323$

---

$t=0$

$$P(0)=\frac{P_l}{1-c}=76.212 $$

$t=30$

$$P(30)= \frac{76.212 *(1-c) }{1-ce^{-k*30}}=122.775$$

$t=60$

$$P(60)= \frac{76.212 *(1-c) }{1-ce^{-k*60}}=179.323$$

can use newtons method and matlab if can see how  put in form $f(x)$ and find the  roots. Tryied to tell sage and wolframm alpha to solve for constants but having issues

---

---

Comment: This is analytically solvable, for example, $k$ solves $$e^{-30k}=\frac{P(0)\cdot(P(60)-P(30))}{P(60)\cdot(P(30)-P(0))}$$

Comment: Using Mathematica: $$\text{c}=-\frac{43199169104443}{11915628909732},\text{p}=\frac{2204591920567}{6253938440},\text{k}=\frac{1}{30}\cdot\ln\left(\frac{2783272283}{1436545392}\right)$$